# Simple php page gives 404 error in Magento

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, magento

For testing purpose, I created a folder and created a test.php file in my magento site.

It contains:

```
<?
echo "Hello";
?>
```

It works on one machine but not another machine.
I chmod 777 to the file but it didn't work.
If I create a test.html file it works fine.

I guess that it's configuration issue.
How do I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Never mind. chmod 755 fixed the problem.